# Why doesn't git-svn use the Subversion repositories UUID instead of its URL

Tags: svn, git-svn

Relocating a git-svn mirror of a Subversion repository isn't trivial:

[git-svn: what’s the equivalent to `svn switch —relocate`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268736/git-svn-whats-the-equivalent-to-svn-switch-relocate)

So why doesn't git-svn use the repository's UUID instead of its URL in the git-svn-id?  The UUID uniquely identifies the repository, so it seems a natural identifier to use and would handle relocatations much easier.

Answer (score 2):

The git wiki has the answer, use the first method documented here:

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnSwitch

I just tested it on a test repo and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your question, but git-svn uses the repo UUID *as well* as the URL.  Both must be correct for git-svn not to print `Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history`.  I really wish it'd output something like 'repo UUID doesn't match' as I just spent several hours trying to figure this out...

Comment: Having both seems redundant.  It seems that just using the UUID would be sufficient.