# git svn repository changed domain name, how to fix?

Tags: git-svn

I'm using git to track a SVN repository. It's all working fine, but now the domain name of the repository changed and I need to commit my changes back to SVN. Except for git svn rebase & git svn dcommit wont work since the domain name has changed. How can I change the repository to track the new location? I already tried editing .git/config SVN URL, but that won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git-svn: what's the equivalent to \`svn switch --relocate\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268736/git-svn-whats-the-equivalent-to-svn-switch-relocate)

Answer (score 3):

[This site says](http://www.sanityinc.com/articles/relocating-git-svn-repositories) you need to create a new git-svn clone from the new svn URL, then copy any local changes into it.

You could try [GitSvnSwitch](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSvnSwitch) but I think its only for relocating within a svn repo (ie svn switch, not svn relocate)

Edit: Or we could both see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268736/git-svn-whats-the-equivalent-to-svn-switch-relocate) :)

Comment: WOW. Thats a lot of work for something which seems 'simple'. I'll try it out, thanks for the help.

Comment: gitsvnswitch is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem after I changed the name of my repository. I changed the .git/config SVN url as you did, and then ran `git pull` to update my repo to the latest version, merged the new files, and then was able to run `git push` with no issues.

What error did git give when it wouldn't let you push? Before I pulled and merged the latest version of the repo, mine said `! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)`, which basically is git's way of saying "Your version of the repo is too old... run `git pull` first..."

Answer (score 0):

If only the domain name changed, you could simply edit your /etc/hosts file (or whatever the equivalent is over in Windows land) to let the old name point to the new address.

Comment: I tried it but for some reason its not working. And I cant seem to fix it. But I'd like to know how to fix this the poper way, using git, since the location might change aswell in the (near) future.