# git-svn after an SVN repository is moved?

Tags: svn, git-svn

We recently moved our SVN server from one data center to another, and the IP of the server has changed.  I used `svn switch --relocate old_url new_url` to update my actual working copy, and that was happy.

However, I do most of my work in a local git version of the repository (using git-svn, obviously).  After moving the SVN server, I updated the URL for the repo in `.git/config`, but when I try to use `dcommit`, I receive this error:

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at /home/me/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 520.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this isn't something that git-svn supports directly. The biggest hurdle is that git-svn uses the "git-svn-id" (visible in the commit log for each commit) to uniquely identify commits from SVN -- and the SVN URL is part of this ID. If the URL changes, it pretty much invalidates all of your existing history.

There are workarounds described [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnSwitch) which look like they should work, but they aren't exactly simple and I haven't tried any of them myself.

Comment: Thanks.  I had feared that this would be the case, but I'm not too worried about losing my work.  I can always pull in my branches after re-importing the SVN stuff.

Comment: I have tried the workaround described in the link at [GitSvnSwitch](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnSwitch) and it did work for me.

Comment: Yes, using the same `url` and `rewriteRoot` in my `.git/config` did the trick for me too!  Fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with git-svn by cloning both repos, merging them, then rebuilding the git-svn metadata.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880050/161298).