# Replay local git-svn history to new svn server (lost access to old svn server)

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I had an old svn server and used `git-svn` to maintain a local copy of the entire history on my machine. I have since lost access to the old svn server but I still have a working git-svn repo on my local machine.

Now I would like to export my local repository to a new svn server. The server is set up and ready to go but I can't find a way to get the full history on there.

I already tried following a procedure for [pushing an existing git repository to svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn), but I get the following errors when doing `git svn fetch`:

```
Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.4c33e94a-e75c-4361-a8fc-dfd8a39081c9
Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.4c33e94a-e75c-4361-a8fc-dfd8a39081c9
Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.4c33e94a-e75c-4361-a8fc-dfd8a39081c9
Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.4c33e94a-e75c-4361-a8fc-dfd8a39081c9
Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.4c33e94a-e75c-4361-a8fc-dfd8a39081c9
Invalid filesystem revision number: No such reported revision '1568' found in the repository. at /usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 300.
```

I think the problem is related to the "git-svn-id". Since my local copy is a `git-svn` repository, each commit is identified by a "git-svn-id"  that includes the URL and revision number of the old svn server. It seems that the revision number must match on the new server (which of course it doesn't). It might be related to the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4694927/5470871), but the workaround this refers to requires that you still have access to the old svn repository (which I don't).

I'm stuck so any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: rewriteRoot + rewriteUUID (found in [Git-Wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnSwitch#Using_rewriteRoot))?

Comment: I haven't been able to make that work. Do you have any more specific information?

Comment: No. I even *don't use* Git