# How to switch svn repositories using git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a number of git projects created as clones of SVN repositories using git-svn. We have migrated our SVN repositories to a new provider so the URL has now changed. How can I update the remote SVN URL of my git clone?

One possibility is that I re-clone from the new SVN repository but I'd prefer not to do that as the process can take days when pulling in the entire history.

Another way to put this question would be, where does git store information about the location of the remote SVN repository you're working with? I.e. where does the URL information come from when you type 'git svn info'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git-svn: what's the equivalent to \`svn switch --relocate\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268736/git-svn-whats-the-equivalent-to-svn-switch-relocate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git-svn: what's the equivalent to \`svn switch --relocate\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268736/git-svn-whats-the-equivalent-to-svn-switch-relocate)

Comment: Rather than being a _"duplicate"_, this question is actually **better** and easier to find for Git users because that question was asked using SVN specific terms.

Answer (score 28):

I found a page in the git wiki which answers exactly my question:

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnSwitch

> - Edit the svn-remote url URL in .git/config to point to the new domain name
> - Run git svn fetch - This needs to fetch at least one new revision from svn!
> - Change svn-remote url back to the original url
> - Run git svn rebase -l to do a local rebase (with the changes that came in with the last fetch operation)
> - Change svn-remote url back to the new url
> - Run git svn rebase should now work again!
>
> This will only work, if the git svn fetch step actually fetches
>   anything! (Took me a while to discover that... I had to put in a dummy
>   revision to our svn repository to make it happen!)

Comment: Some links on that page are dead now. Also, it would be nice if you could put the actual solution here, not just the link.

Answer (score 23):

Following the [same url [1]](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnSwitch), but with an updated solution, it becomes much easier.

Inside `.git/config`, in the `[svn-remote]` section, set **`url`** to the **new** URL, and set **`rewriteRoot`** to the **old** URL:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url         = https://new.svn-server.net/svn/root
    rewriteRoot = https://old.svn-server.net/svn/root
```

The same can be surely done via the `git config ...` commands from the guide:

```
$ git config --local --replace-all svn-remote.<name>.rewriteRoot `git config --local --get svn-remote.<name>.url`
$ git config --local --replace-all svn-remote.<name>.url <new_url>
```

Then it just works, for me I don't have to make any dummy revision even though there's no new revisions on the new server. Interestingly, `git svn info` reports the same old URL, but with the new URL as Repository Root:

```
$ git svn info
Path: .
URL: <old-url>
Repository Root: <new-url>
```

[1] https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnSwitch

Comment: This works for me too. I have a server outside of intranet, I have to use sshfs to mount it as local directory. After I changed the repository location, I had successfully did the `git svn dcommit` using this `rewriteRoot` config method. Thanks!

Comment: [The git-scm docs for rewriteRoot](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-svn-remoteltnamegtrewriteRoot) warn: "Since the noMetadata, *rewriteRoot*, rewriteUUID, useSvnsyncProps and useSvmProps options all affect the metadata generated and used by git svn; they must be set in the configuration file *before any history* is imported and these settings should *never be changed* once they are set."