# relocate git-svn repository with remotes

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have been trying to relocate a git-svn working copy of a subversion repository that has switched locations.  I have followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268736/git-svn-whats-the-equivalent-to-svn-switch-relocate), but when I do so, it errors out at the final step stating that it can't deal with certain remotes:

$ git svn rebase 
refs/remotes/abranch_0.1: '' not found in '/branches/abranch'

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?  It looks like these branches and/or remotes are still pointing to the wrong place, but I don't see where to change this.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this weird problem and wanted to record it here in case anyone encounters this problem.  I noticed that in .git/config, the following lines appeared twice:

```
branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

For whatever reason, these same lines were repeated identically two times.  I tried deleting the extra set of lines, and then repeating the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268736/git-svn-whats-the-equivalent-to-svn-switch-relocate?lq=1), and now everything seems to be working. I have no idea why that fixed things, but there you go.

Cheers,
David