# How to rename upstream trunk in git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a local it repository that was fetched from upstream git-svn repository with git-svn. At some moment, upstream repository's trunk (it has nonstandard layout) was renamed there.

From that moment i can no longer dcommit or fetch new commits. If i try and change (manually) svn-remote.remotename.url, i get error "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history", which kind of makes sense but helps me none.

Is there a way to solve the issue that doe not involve fetching again?

I have tried setting rewriteRoot property (to new url), also without any discernible result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to solve the issue that doe not involve fetching again?

Not really:

- The `svn-remote.svn.rewriteRoot` property was [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061493/6309)
- Modifying `svn-remote url` was [detailed there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268736/git-svn-whats-the-equivalent-to-svn-switch-relocate%EF%BC%89)

Both involves `git-svn clone` and working from there.